# Webpack Circular dependencies with dynamic import

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting, dynamic-import

Hi i am building an app where i found myslef doing circular dependency but webpack does not give me circular deps error. so i wanted to understand what actually is happening here .

so here is how my module imports are done

1.`root.router.config.js`

```
import React from 'react'

const AsyncAdmin = React.lazy(()=>import('./Modules/Admin'));

export ROUTER_CONFIG = {
   admin: {
      component: AsyncAdmin,
      path: '/'
   } 
}
```

2.`Modules/Admin/index.js`

```
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import MODULE_ROUTER from './Admin.router.config'

 // renders router from this MODULE_ROUTER
```

3. `Modules/Admin/Admin.router.config.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import {ROUTER_CONFIG as ROOT_ROUTER_CONFIG} from '../../root.router.config' // should be cyclic import error but its not

const base = ROOT_ROUTER_CONFIG['admin'].path

const AsyncDashboard = React.lazy(()=>import('./Routes/Dashboard'));

export ROUTER_CONFIG = {
   dashbaord: {
      component: Dashboard,
      path: base + 'dashboard'
   } 
}
```

if you see the imports here

`Modules/Admin/Admin.router.config.js` =imports> `root.router.config` =imports(lazy)=> `Modules/Admin/Admin.router.config.js`

this will be a definite circular import if i am not using lazy/dynamic import.

i want to know why webpack treats it differently and why its not a circular import error.

should i avoid it and move to a better approach where there is no chance of circular imports ?

and if i continue to do this. will it have any impact on my bundled code ?

Answer (score 0):

Abstract the "path" to a constants folder/file and it should resolve the issue. In general, webpack aside, you should try avoiding circular dependencies.